# Submitted Revit 2022 model to Forge. It accepted SVF format but returned PDF's

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Submitted Revit 2022 model to Forge. Accepted SVF format but returned PDF's

acceptedJobs":{"output":{"formats":{"0":{"type":"svf","views":{"0":"2d","1":"3d"}}}}}}

snippet from manifest:

{"urn":"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW5lcnRpYXNhbmRib3hfdGVzdC9pbmVydGlhc2FuZGJveDByMjIuemlw/output/Resource/Sheet/A101 - LEVEL 1 FLOOR PLAN 1420741/pdf/A101 - LEVEL 1 FLOOR PLAN.pdf"

Model works as expected in 2021 format, I used the same model upgraded from 2021 to 2022 and it changes from producing the expected svf to pdf.

Comment: what do you want us to help you with?
please edit your question with what you want to achieve and what you already tried

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Feb 2023

Now we have an advanced option to control if the resulting 2D views will be converted as PDFs.
Please, refer to https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/advanced-option-rvtdwg-2d-views-svf2-post-job

...

When you trigger the conversion, 2D sheets for Revit file with 2022 and higher versions are exported as PDF.
2D properties are supported by [GET properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/).